# Sticky headers in table not completely hiding table data below (on scroll)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table

I've created a table with react-table and made sticky headers with CSS:

```
th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; /* required for the stickiness */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

[image: Look closely to see the issue]

yet, it's not perfect, when I scroll I can see some of the scrolled text above the table header.

Did anyone face this issue?

Comment: Image is broken

Comment: We won't be able to help you because this seems to be a CSS issue and you haven't included most of the relevant CSS. If I had to guess I'd say it's got something to do with some `margin` or `top` needs to be `-1px` or less

Comment: Thank you @Dominik it was close enough for me to solve the problem!
`top: -5px; /* the fix */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move the top a little farther:
`th { position: sticky; top: -5px; }`

I created a bigger heading cell so it won't be noticed using `padding-top:5px`